# How do I disable a Survey until video is completely watched first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

We have been struggling to come up with a solution for this problem.

We know what solution we think is appropriate. We just don't know how to go about it.

We have six videos we would like our users to watch.

Each video is accompanied by a survey.

Each survey can have one or more questions.

Here is a screenshot of how the videos and surveys are organized:

[image: Videos and associated surveys]

Then here is the code that produces the videos and Survey on the attached screenshot.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="videoTraining.aspx.vb" Inherits="videoTraining" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Training Videos</title>
<meta name="DownloadOptions" content="noopen" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(path)
   {
     window.open(path, '', 'width=780,height=680,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes');
   }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" class="blink" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Garamond"
                    Font-Size="x-Large" Style="z-index: 100; color: #ff0000;left:620px; position: absolute; top: 112px"
                    Width="493px"></asp:Label>
<div id='outer-wrapper'>
  <div id='wrap2'>
   <div>
    <br />
      <table>    
       <tr>
        <td class="style2"><img id="Img1" src="~/App_Themes/Silver/images/line.gif" alt="" runat="server" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap" class="style2">
         <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
          <ItemTemplate>
           <ul>
            <li>
             <asp:HyperLink  ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#254117" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("url", "javascript:openWindow(&#039;{0}&#039;);") %>' Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' /><br />
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#dc381f" CssClass="generaltext" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
             <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#614051" NavigateUrl='<%# "start.aspx?testid=" & Eval("SurveyId") %>' Text='Take a quiz'></asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString.ProviderName %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [url], [Title], [Description], [SurveyId] FROM [Survey]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
       </tr>                                         
      </table> 
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This works fine as is.

Here is where we are having problems.

Users would often take a shortcut of either guessing the questions associated with a video, or watching the videos randomly.

As a result, they would end guessing the questions till they pass but in practice, are unable to demonstrate enough understanding of the instructions from the video.

This is creating a big problem for the company.

I have, therefore, been tasked with making sure that the following happens if possible.

1, disable the quizzes until the user has clicked and watched the video.
2, Avoid a user from skipping one video for another.

For instance, users should not skip video 1 to watch video 2.

So, essentially, enable video 1 and disable everything else till the user has watched the video.

Then enable the quiz for that video.

Continue this until all videos are watched.

Any ideas how to go about this?

It would seem like JavaScript or JQuery is the way to go but I am stumped as to how to go about it.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your item ID to the ID of the matching control, i.e.

```
<a id='videoLink_<%# Eval("ID") %>' href='videoLink" class="disabled">
<a id='surveyLink_<%# Eval("ID") %>' href='surveyLink" class="disabled">
```

...

then in document.ready() use jquery select to enable the first video only:

```
//enable first video
$("[id^='videoLink_']:first").removeClass("disabled");
```

Not sure how you'll handle video watched event but in another JS function:

```
function videoWatched(videoLinkID){
  //get item id from the watched video:
  var itemID = videoLinkID.split("videoLink_")[1];
  //enable the matching survey link:
  $("#surveyLink_" + itemID).removeClass("disabled");
}
```

and some css:

```
.disabled:hover{
cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been pretty frustrated by this.

I am trying your suggestions now. I will post an update. Please be on the lookout.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @artm,

Thanks again. I posted the code I am using to produce the link on the screenshot I posted.

Is there anyway you could help use that code and integrate with yours?

I am a bit confused as to how to make your code and mine work.

Comment: Kenny, replace  asp:hyperlinks you have in your code with a links in my sample and add the JS code I sent. The idea is that when you use current item's ID in the link's ID, then when a video is watched you can find which a to enable. Your video link will be <a id='videoLink_135' ... > and your survey link will be <a id='surveyLink_135' ... >. So when a video is watched you can find from the video's id which survey link to enable.

Comment: Not sure how I can replace my links with your code.

I must be missing something.

They are two totally different things.